# Django Querysets: using select_related to return objects from a set of foreign keys

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have an ArticlePage model which has a foriegnkey to a City model, and I'd like to efficiently use QuerySet to get a set of models.City containing all City instances that have been referenced by an ArticlePage.

```
class ArticlePage(Page):
    #...
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    #...
```

Then in a view:

```
qs = ArticlePage.objects.filter(city__isnull=False).filter(city__name__icontains=self.q).select_related('city')
```

So I've tried many permutations of the above query, and none of them return the desired result.  All the results are a set of ArticlePage type instead of City.

All I'm trying to do is return a set of results of type City that contains every City object that is referenced by an ArticlePage, but I'm going insane trying to make this happen with django querysets, and I'm sure I'm just doing something very silly.  Appreciate any advise here.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand what you want, but if you want `City` instances, why are you querying `ArticlePage` instead of `City`?

Comment: I recommend to rename the question to something easier searchable by other people and edit the first sentence, if you agree. I believe that there should be still similar (or duplicate) questions, but none can be easily found and your question could be useful.

Comment: answered below, I've updated the title and first sentence to hopefully be more searchable, let me know if it could be phrased better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [select-related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), just cached related objects, if you need queryset of `City` you need rewrite you qs, somethig like:

```
qs_a = ArticlePage.objects.filter(city__isnull=False).values_list('city__pk', flat=True)
qs = City.objects.filter(name__icontains=self.q, pk__in=qs_a)
```

hope it help

Comment: This is an optimal solution, because `qs_a` is a query set that is lazy executed and even never executed in this case separately because both query sets are compiled to one SQL command: `SELECT id, ... FROM app_city WHERE name LIKE '...' AND id IN (SELECT city_id FROM app_articlepage WHERE city_id IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: Thankyou, it was the pk__in arg that I'd manged to miss originally!